# Transient Graphic Scale

Tags: graphics, zooming, autocad, transient

I am using transient graphic to draw a circle but its diameters seems on screen greater than normal

I tried to control ratio of the current screen size but I couldn't

```
            ViewTableRecord view =new ViewTableRecord();
            view.CenterPoint = min2d + ((max2d - min2d) / 2.0);
            view.Height= max2d.Y - min2d.Y;
            view.Width = max2d.X - min2d.X;
            ed.SetCurrentView(view);

            double dViewRatio= (view.Width / view.Height);
            Point3d pn = db.Extmin;
            Point3d px = db.Extmax;

            Extents3d ents;
            using (Line acLine = new Line(pn, px))
            {
                 ents = new Extents3d(acLine.Bounds.Value.MinPoint,
                                            acLine.Bounds.Value.MaxPoint);
            }

            double dWidth = ents.MaxPoint.X - ents.MinPoint.X;
            double dHeight = ents.MaxPoint.Y - ents.MinPoint.Y;
```

Comment: Transient graphics use the same units as graphical entities. A transient circle which radius is equal to 10 units is exactly the same as a circle entity with the same radius.

Comment: You are right but in case of Zoom.Extent  it draws Ø10   as Ø20

Comment: You should show the code you're using to create transient graphics.

Comment: Vector3d v3d = new Vector3d(0, 0, 1); 
                        Circle circle = new Circle(prResult1.Value, v3d, cap);
                        m_mrkers.Add(circle);
                        circle.ColorIndex = 9;
                        aGi.TransientManager.CurrentTransientManager.AddTransient(circle, aGi.TransientDrawingMode.DirectShortTerm, 128, intColl);

Comment: Whatever the zoom factor, the circle radius will still be equal to 'cap' value (in drawing units).